# Magento2 2.3.3 not creating symlinks for static files anymore

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

After a lot of searching on google, I hope someone can help me out.

Magento2 version 2.3.3 is running on nginx with the sample config from Magento. PHP 7.1.33 is running via fcgi.

The developer mode is set through the cmd tool and also through the nginx ENV params.
Unfortunately for pub/static all files are copied, which leads to the annoying fact, that I have to rerun `bin/magento setup:static:deploy` for every change to see it in the frontend (which takes a lot time).

I already checked `app/etc/di.xml` for the `<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>` part. 
I checked permissions. 
But Magento is only copying the files - no symlinks.

Hope somebody can help!

Comment: I think you need to be in developper mode to have symlinks. You can see your current mode with "bin/magento deploy:mode:show" and you can set it with : "php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developper"

Comment: @CarloRicci thanks for your fast reply, I just testet this but unfortunately no success. Magento creates copies

Comment: For all who are suffering for the same problem, and for me as a reference :) - the problem seems to lay in the wrong magento2 workflow mode. Somehow the workflow mode (System Configuration > Extended > Developer > Fronten Workflow) was set to server side, but not intentionally. Switching back to client side resolved the problem!